# Share folders between users

Tags: folder

I would like to share my "Videos" folder with another user on the same computer. I created a group to which I added the folder as well as both the users. However, when I log into the other user, I still cannot view the contents. Any idea how I can do this?

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the Elementary OS forum!

Since you have already created the group "*share*" and you are confident that **both** accounts are members of the group "*share*" then setting the POSIX permissions are relatively straight forward.

1. Go to Applications -> Terminal (or Win+T)
2. In Terminal type: `cd ~`
**WARNING:** The next two commands use the recursive flag!  This means that the command will set the owner and group (then the file permissions) from that point down.  Please follow **all** instructions carefully...
3. Type: `sudo chown -R rahul:share Videos`
**NOTE:** You will be prompted for your login password.
I included the username from your screen shot.
4. Type: `sudo chmod -R 775 Videos`
NOTE: This will give full read, write and execute permissions to your rahul account and the "*share*" group.
5. Type Cont+D to exit the Terminal.

At this point, you and anyone in group "*share*" will have full access to rahul's Videos folder.  Furthermore, anyone in the "*share*" group will be able to make **changes** (add, edit or delete) files from rahul's Videos folder.

Good luck.